# pygame zero - moving graphics downwards

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics, pgzero

A graphic should fall at a random position from top to bottom. When the graphic has fallen down, and has "disappeared" from the screen, it should fall again at a random position from top to bottom. I always get the following error message: "empty range for randrange() (0,-799, -799)".
Before the graphic appears in the game window it must have a negative y-coordinate? So, how can i make falling objects?

```
from random import randint
import pygame

WIDTH   = 800
HEIGHT  = 800

apple = Actor("apple")
apple.pos = randint(0, 800), randint(0, -800)

score = 0

def draw():
    screen.clear()
    apple.draw()
    screen.draw.text("Punkte: " + str(score), (700, 5), color = "white")


def update():
    if apple.y < 800:
        apple.y = apple.y + 4   
    else:
        apple.x = randint(0, 800)
        apple.y = randint(0, -800)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use [`random.randint(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html), then `a` has to be less or equal than `b`:

<s>`apple.y = randint(0, -800)`</s>

```py
apple.y = randint(-800, 0)
```

Note, `randint` returns a random integer `N` such that `a <= N <= b`.

---

Note, if you want to start the `apple` at the top of the screen, them the y coordinate has to be set 0 (or *-radius* of the apple):

```py
apple.x = randint(0, 800)
apple.y = 0
```

What you actually do is to set the `apple` at a random position above off screen.

Comment: i see, i was thinking wrong, with apple.y = randint(-800, 0) it is working now :)